# Xna Game referencing Game in update

Tags: xna-4.0

Hi I have a problem with my XNA game im trying to reference Game in another class but every time i try something it says no suitable way to override its so i can use Mouse.SetPosition(window.ClientBounds.Width / 2, window.ClientBounds.Height / 2); in another class other than game1.cs my code for game1 is

```
namespace _3d
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


    MouseState mState;

    List<gameObject> gameobjectlist = new List<gameObject>();

    terrain Terrain;
    Camera mycam;

    Turret_Base turretBase;
    Turret_Barrel turretBarrel;
    //physicsObject Missile;


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>

    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here



        mycam = new Camera(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f),
            (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 
        (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height,
        1.0f, 10000.0f, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
        mycam.Position = new Vector3(0.0f, 53.0f, 155.0f);

        //MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        //Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(mouseState.Y, mouseState.X, 0.0f);





        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Terrain = new terrain("models/terrain/desert", Content);
        turretBase = new Turret_Base("models/turret/Turret_Base", Content);
        turretBarrel = new Turret_Barrel("models/turret/Turret_Barrel", Content);
        //Missile = new physicsObject("models/turret/ammo", Content);

        gameobjectlist.Add(Terrain);
        gameobjectlist.Add(turretBase);
        gameobjectlist.Add(turretBarrel);
        gameobjectlist.Add(mycam);


        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void update(GameTime gameTime)
    {


        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        foreach (gameObject go in gameobjectlist)
        {
        }




        mycam.update(gameTime);

        Terrain.update(gameTime);
        turretBase.update(gameTime);
        turretBarrel.update(gameTime);

        if (exitGame() == false)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        // TODO: Add your update logic here


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        foreach (gameObject go in gameobjectlist)
        {
        }


        // TODO: Add your drawing code here


        Terrain.draw(mycam);
        turretBase.draw(mycam);
        turretBarrel.draw(mycam);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    bool exitGame()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            Exit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    } 
   }
```

and the class i am trying to put it into is >>

```
{
class Turret_Base : gameObject 



 {
    Turret_Barrel Parent;

    public Turret_Base(string fileName, ContentManager content, Turret_Barrel parent =      
    null)
        : base(fileName, content)
    {

        GameWindow window;
        Parent = parent;
        Pitch = 25;
        Yaw = 0;
        Roll = 0;
        Position = new Vector3(0, 50, 120);
        Scale = 0.1f; //Base Transform

    }

    public override void update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        float dt = (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        // mouse movement
        //MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();

        //Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(mState.X, Position.Y, mState.Y);

        //Position = newPos;

        KeyboardState keyboardstate = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            Position -= Vector3.UnitZ * 25.0f * dt;
        if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            Position -= Vector3.UnitX * 25.0f *dt;
        if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            Position += Vector3.UnitZ * 25.0f * dt;
        if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            Position += Vector3.UnitX * 25.0f * dt;



        base.update(gametime);


    }
}
```

}

sorry if its a obvious mistake

Thanks

Comment: You *really* need to edit this question and improve it. If you're getting an error message, please post the specific error message and the line and surrounding code that it refers to. Just dumping your whole code isn't helpful - especially as it's not actually calling `SetPosition` anywhere.

Comment: @Guru `[game-development]` was [*intentionally burninated*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140497/135887).  Why did you recreate it and add it to over 40 questions?

Comment: oh..thanks for this link Sir...now only come to know...thanks a lot.